# SQLite - COALESCE breaks result order

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite table (for messages). The table has two columns for order: `created` and `sent`. I need to get result sorted by `sent` field (descent), but if there is 0, then by `created` field (also descent).

I'm using SQL-function `COALESCE`, but the order of the result is wrong.

Normal result (without `COALESCE`):

```
SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY sent DESC
┌─────────────┬──────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ external_id │   body   │  created   │    sent    │
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │    qw    │ 1463793500 │ 1463793493 │ <-
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │  huyak   │ 1463783516 │ 1463662248 │
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │   tete   │ 1463783516 │ 1463662248 │
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │    Te    │ 1463783516 │ 1463662248 │
└─────────────┴──────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

Wrong result (with COALESCE):

```
SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY COALESCE(sent,created)=0 DESC
┌─────────────┬──────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ external_id │   body   │  created   │    sent    │
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │    Te    │ 1463783516 │ 1463662248 │
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │  huyak   │ 1463783516 │ 1463662248 │
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │   tete   │ 1463783516 │ 1463662248 │
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │    qw    │ 1463793500 │ 1463793493 │ <-
└─────────────┴──────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

I tried to remove expression `=0`, then the order is correct, but that request doesn't work correctly if `sent = 0`:

```
SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY COALESCE(sent,created) DESC
┌─────────────┬──────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ external_id │   body   │  created   │    sent    │
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │    qw    │ 1463793500 │ 1463793493 │ <-
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │  huyak   │ 1463783516 │ 1463662248 │
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │   tete   │ 1463783516 │ 1463662248 │
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │    Te    │ 1463783516 │ 1463662248 │
└─────────────┴──────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
but
┌─────────────┬──────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ external_id │   body   │  created   │    sent    │
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │    Te    │ 1463783516 │ 1463662248 │
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │  huyak   │ 1463783516 │ 1463662248 │
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │   tete   │ 1463783516 │ 1463662248 │
├─────────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│     ...     │    qw    │ 1463793500 │     0      │ <-
└─────────────┴──────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

Does anyone know why it's happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Imagine my surprise that I found something on SO using "huyak" as a keyword search. Don't ask why please :)

Comment: @alecxe easter eggs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COALESCE` handles NULLs, it won't help you here. It will always return `sent` to you. If you compare its result to zero you're only sorting based on whether `sent` is zero or not. You'll have to use a `CASE`

```
... ORDER BY CASE sent WHEN 0 THEN created ELSE sent END DESC;
```

If you had NULLs where there is no timestamp then you could use `COALESCE` without the comparison.

Comment: Thanks for information, your query works. About performance - which option is better: `COALSCE` (I can change my code so there will be `null` instead 0) or `CASE`?

Comment: @Dmitry Most likely COALESCE is better, but it's mostly about data integrity. NULL is "no value" and should be used as such if possible. You'll have to benchmark your case to see what's more performant.

Answer (score 0):

COALESCE handles NULLs, not zeros.

You can convert zero values to NULL with the [nullif() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#nullif):

```
SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY COALESCE(NULLIF(sent,0),created) DESC;
```